# Posting data using Javascript $ajax(settings)

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Requirement:Using Javascript I have to do a "Post".Also I need to pass 2 inputs.One is a 'query' parameter type of data-type 'long'  and the other is a 'body' parameter type of data-type 'Array[long]'.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
    };

    $.ajax({
       url: "https://api.XXXX.com.au/XXXX/api/V1/XXXXX/some_webservice?param1= 5637161343",

        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
           xhrObj.setRequestHeader("ContentType","application/json;charset=utf-8");

        type: "POST",

        // Request body
       data:{Param2:[5637151026]}



    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Issue:Not able to post.i think I am going wrong with the syntax of the 'body parameter' .

I request your help to solve this issue!.Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: That would be a valid response, the content you're trying to fetch hasn't changed, so it's gotten from cache ?

Comment: Yes.the data is not from cache.I am not getting anything in the response object which in turn leads the flow to fail() rather than done()

Answer (score 0):

When query parameter of ajax call remains the same then some browsers will return the previous response from cache. So, to prevent this please add dummy parameter to the ajax call which will change on every ajax request. like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
    };

    $.ajax({
       url: "https://api.XXXX.com.au/XXXX/api/V1/XXXXX/some_webservice?param1= 5637161343",
        cache : false,
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
           xhrObj.setRequestHeader("ContentType","application/json;charset=utf-8");

        type: "POST",

        // Request body
       data:{Param2:[5637151026], extraParam : Math.random() }



    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

Here due to `Math.random()` browser will not give cached response. Because everytime extraParam's value is different. Also I added `cache : false`. that is default functionality of jQuery to prevent cache.

Comment: Yes.I am-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It means there is some problem in your server side code OR you are not posting correct parameters. Please chek

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.Problem was with the way I bind the Request body-

```
$(function() {
var params = {
    // Request parameters
};var info=[5637151026];$.ajax({
   url: "https://api.XXXX.com.au/XXXX/api/V1/XXXXX/some_webservice?param1= 5637161343",
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        // Request headers
       xhrObj.setRequestHeader("ContentType","application/json;charset=utf-8");dataType:"json",type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(info)


})
.done(function(data) {
    alert("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});});
```